# JBoss AS 7.1 - running schedule using @Schedule annotation

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, scheduler

Anyone know how to make @Schedule annotation work on JBoss AS 7?

I know that on Glassfish-3.1.2 it works out-of-box.

I try this:

```
@ManagedBean
@Stateless(name="ImportStatementSchedule")
public class ImportStatementSchedule implements Serializable{
private Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Schedule(minute="*")
    public void executeImport(){
        _log.info("Scheduled task started");
    }

}
```

I expect receive log message every minute, but nothing ;)

I checked these forum threads, but nothing helps :

https://community.jboss.org/message/623574

https://community.jboss.org/message/621893

https://community.jboss.org/message/637567

A have JBoss AS 7.1.1-Final

Maybe I forgot something, please can anyone point me to right way?

**UPDATE:**

I know that JBoss register my EJB to JNDI :

```
11:07:05,548 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-6) JNDI bindings for session bean named ImportStatementSchedule in deployment unit deployment "finadv.war" are as follows:

    java:global/finadv/ImportStatementSchedule!finadv.bean.ImportStatementSchedule
    java:app/finadv/ImportStatementSchedule!finadv.bean.ImportStatementSchedule
    java:module/ImportStatementSchedule!finadv.bean.ImportStatementSchedule
    java:global/finadv/ImportStatementSchedule
    java:app/finadv/ImportStatementSchedule
    java:module/ImportStatementSchedule
```

**UPDATE2**

It has been solved as mentioned in comments

Comment: See this thread, particularly the "hour" parameter:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246606/java-ee-scheduler-is-not-called

Answer (score 6):

Timer service is EJB service. `ImportStatementSchedule` should be a `@Stateless` or `@Singleton` session bean. From the EJB 3.1 Specification, Section 18.2:

> For automatically created timers, the timeout method may be a method that is annotated with the Schedule annotation. Timers can be created for stateless session beans, singleton session beans, mes- sage-driven beans, and 2.1 entity beans. Timers cannot be created for stateful session beans.

The `INFO` log statement is misleading. JBoss does not register an EJB. It just uses the same naming scheme as defined by the `@ManagedBean` annotation (Javadoc):

> [..] Managed Bean names must be unique within a Java EE module. For each named Managed Bean, Java EE containers must make available the following entries in JNDI, using the same naming scheme used for EJB components.
>   In the application namespace:
>
> `java:app/<module-name>/<bean-name>`
>
> In the module namespace of the module containing the Managed Bean:
>
> `java:module/<bean-name>`

Comment: +1 for good reference, but I tried before both Stateless or Singleton annotation, now I know that problem was as @Nick Wilson mentioned in hour parameter.

Comment: thx, @rkosegi. does that mean that you can use `@Schedule` without using `@Stateless` or `@Singleton`?

Comment: No, it means that I was not able to make it work until I set hour parameter to "*". Currently I'm using Stateless annotation and it works.

Answer (score 4):

I can add, that if you write

`@Schedule(minute="*")`

it will only fire at midnight. Because the hour parameter is default: **0**.

Try:

`@Schedule(minute = "/1", hour = "")`

or something like this.
In my case it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify **hours**, try:

```
@Schedule(hour="\*", minute="\*")
```